# SPFx Unit Testing with newer SPFx and @pnpjs Version

Tags: unit-testing, spfx, pnp-js, sharepointframework

I already implemented SPFx unit testing with Jest in older SPFx projects (V. 1.11) and pnpjs v2. It was tricky, but with some good articles I made it work.

Now I tried it with the SPFx Version 1.16.1 and @pnps library version 3 and I've serveral problems.

My Question: Is there a current howto or documentation about implementing SPFx Unit Testing with Jest and the new SPFx/@pnpjs versions?
Most Articles which I found are from 2018-2020...

These Articles helped my by setup for the 1.11 SPFx Version:

[Howto From Elio Struyf](https://www.eliostruyf.com/sharepoint-framework-unit-tests-with-jest/)

[Sample from sp-dev-fx-webparts](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-jest-testing)

[To fix some problems](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/1425)

Thanks!